# plotly.js lag problem. my project is running slow

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I have a project where I created the backend with flask. It reads the data from the csv file and transfers it to html. It reads data every second with Ajax. Then I visualize the data with plotly.js. With Ajax, every get operation comes with a delay.I am working with approximately 2000 data.

However, there is a delay in my code. How can I refactor this code? What can I do to avoid delay?

```js
$(function requestData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/deneme3",
    success: function (data) {
      //console.log('success',data);
      //console.log('success',data[0]);
      //console.log('success',data[1]);
      var enlem = [];
      var boylam = [];
      var ch1 = [];
      var ch2 = [];
      var ch3 = [];
      var ch4 = [];
      enlem = data[0];
      boylam = data[1];
      ch1 = data[2];
      ch2 = data[3];
      ch3 = data[4];
      ch4 = data[5];
      //console.log('enlem',enlem);
      //console.log('boylam',boylam);

      var trace1 = {
        x: enlem,
        y: boylam,
        mode: "markers",
        marker: {
          size: 10,
          color: ch1,
          colorbar: { x: -0.2, len: 1 },
          colorscale: "Jet",
        },
      };

      var data = [trace1];

      var layout = {
        title: "Scatter Plot with a Color Dimension",
      };

      Plotly.newPlot("tester", data, layout);

      setInterval(function () {
        var update = {
          x: [[enlem]],
          y: [[boylam]],
        };

        Plotly.extendTraces("tester", update, [0]);
      }, 100);

      //ch1 grafik
      var trace2 = {
        y: ch1,
        type: "scatter",
      };

      var data2 = [trace2];

      var layout2 = {
        title: "CH1",
      };

      Plotly.newPlot("ch1", data2, layout2);

      setInterval(function () {
        var update = {
          y: [[ch1]],
        };

        Plotly.extendTraces("ch1", update, [0]);
      }, 100);

      //ch2 grafik
      var trace3 = {
        y: ch2,
        type: "scatter",
      };

      var data3 = [trace3];

      var layout3 = {
        title: "CH2",
      };

      Plotly.newPlot("ch2", data3, layout3);

      setInterval(function () {
        var update = {
          y: [[ch2]],
        };

        Plotly.extendTraces("ch2", update, [0]);
      }, 100);

      //ch3 grafik
      var trace4 = {
        y: ch3,
        type: "scatter",
      };

      var data4 = [trace4];

      var layout4 = {
        title: "CH3",
      };

      Plotly.newPlot("ch3", data4, layout4);

      setInterval(function () {
        var update = {
          y: [[ch3]],
        };

        Plotly.extendTraces("ch3", update, [0]);
      }, 100);

      //ch4 grafik
      var trace5 = {
        y: ch4,
        type: "scatter",
      };

      var data5 = [trace5];

      var layout5 = {
        title: "CH4",
      };

      Plotly.newPlot("ch4", data5, layout5);

      setInterval(function () {
        var update = {
          y: [[ch4]],
        };

        Plotly.extendTraces("ch4", update, [0]);
      }, 100);
    },
  });

  setTimeout(requestData, 100);
});
```

Also, which of the Ajax and socketio would it make more sense to use?

Comment: What do you mean with "there is a delay in my code"? Either way, those `setInterval`s seem to not make much sense, since you're just repeatedly updating a chart with the same data..?

Comment: Also, the variable initializations in the success function are redundant since you j ust immediately reassign them from the data anyway...

Comment: Data is constantly updated. However, I am giving an example. 15 came in the first loop. 15.25 came in the second loop. 15,25,35 came in the third loop. I guess there is a delay because it is like this.@AKX What can I do about it?

Comment: You should probably be initializing the 5 plots only once, and simply feed them new data in the success function. As it is, the success function repeatedly creates new interval timers - after the first pull, 5 functions are called every 0.1 seconds. After the second, 10 functions are called every 0.1 seconds. After the third pull, 15 functions, etc... And all of them are updating the chart with conflicting data.

Comment: For example, when I write the first graph outside of the function, how do I access the data from the function. @AKX X and Y come from Ajax.

Comment: Just don't add any data yet. Leave X and Y empty.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, something like this might work: initialize empty plots, then just fill in data in the update function:

```js
function plotData(data) {
  const [enlem, boylam, ...chs] = data;
  Plotly.extendTraces("tester", {
    x: [[enlem]],
    y: [[boylam]],
  }, [0]);

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    const j = i + 1;
    Plotly.extendTraces(`ch${j}`, {
      y: [[chs[i]]],
    }, [0]);
  }

  // After success, wait before loading more data
  setTimeout(requestData, 1000);
}

function requestData() {
  // Simulate a successful response that returns 6 numbers.
  plotData([Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()]);
  // If a real endpoint was available, you could do something like
  /*$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/deneme3",
    success: plotData,
  });*/
}

function initialize() {
  Plotly.newPlot("tester", [{
    x: [],
    y: [],
    mode: "markers",
    marker: {
      size: 10,
      colorbar: { x: -0.2, len: 1 },
      colorscale: "Jet",
    },
  }], {
    title: "Scatter Plot with a Color Dimension",
  });
  for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    Plotly.newPlot(`ch${i}`, [{
      y: [],
      type: "scatter",
    }], {
      title: `CH${i}`,
    });
  }
  requestData();  // Fire off first update
}

$(initialize);
```

```css
div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="tester"></div>
<div id="ch1"></div>
<div id="ch2"></div>
<div id="ch3"></div>
<div id="ch4"></div>
```

Comment: deneme:84 Uncaught TypeError: $.load is not a function. Wonder why I'm getting this error

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while since I've used jQuery. Just do `$(initialize);`

Comment: Graphics appear when I run it. However, the data is not coming. @AKX If you are available, can you review if I send the project's github link?

Comment: It's late for me, but I may be available for a paid consultation/mentoring session tomorrow. You can find the link to my Codementor profile on my profile page.

Comment: For what it's worth, I replaced the code sample above with a certifiably working snippet. The only thing that's different is that the data is just random and local, but you can replace that function call with something else.

Comment: Dude, only the data didn't come. There should be a few lines of code for you @AKX

Comment: Any luck, @walrider22? It's not just "a few lines of code" if I don't even know what your endpoint actually produces to the frontend.